# How to show one div at a time with least lines of code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to show only one div at a time once a link is clicked. My codepen I was working on is [here](https://codepen.io/codingwithlaurence/pen/KBYPmO) if someone could take a look. I'm trying to use jQuery so that when an  element inside a  list item is clicked it toggles that div item to display ONLY until another item is clicked which hides the previous item.

```js
$( "#home_div" ).hide();
$( "#about_div" ).hide();

$( "#home" ).click(function() {
 $('#home_div').toggle();
});
$( "#about" ).click(function() {
 $('#about_div').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animate.css@3.5.2/animate.min.css">
</head> 
<body>
<header class="header">
      <ul class="main-nav">
          <li id="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a id="about" href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a id ="portfolio" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a id="contact" href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
           <div id="home_div"></div>
           <div id="about_div"></div>
           <div id="portfolio_div"></div>
           <div id="contact_div"></div>


  
  </header> 
  </body>
```

Comment: hide all first like `$('.header > div').each( (index,item) => { $(item).hide()})`, then show the clicked one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make this work in a generic manner (and therefore keep the JS as short as possible) you can place the `id` of the target content within the `href` property of the `a` elements. Then you can simply `toggle()` the target div whilst hiding its siblings, like this:

```js
$('.main-nav a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $($(this).attr('href')).toggle().siblings().hide();
});
```

```css
#content-container div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="main-nav">
  <li><a href="#home_div">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about_div">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#portfolio_div">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact_div">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="content-container">
  <div id="home_div">Home</div>
  <div id="about_div">About</div>
  <div id="portfolio_div">Portfolio</div>
  <div id="contact_div">Contact</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give all the content a common class. Then use the id of the nav link to create selector for the content to show

```js
$('.main-nav a').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
  // hide all content class and filter the matching id to show
  $('.content').hide().filter('#' + this.id + '_div').show();
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: none
}

.content:first-of-type {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animate.css@3.5.2/animate.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <ul class="main-nav">
      <li><a id="home" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a id="about" href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a id="portfolio" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a id="contact" href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="content" id="home_div">home_div</div>
    <div class="content" id="about_div">about_div</div>
    <div class="content" id="portfolio_div"></div>
    <div class="content" id="contact_div">portfolio_div</div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about zero javascript?  You could change the menu to be labels that tie to radio buttons that control which div shows.  The CSS only shows the div immediately after the radio button that is currently selected, modifiable by clicking any of the menu labels.

```css
[name=mainNavState] { display: none; }
[name=mainNavState] + div { display: none; }
[name=mainNavState]:checked + div { display: inherit; }
```

```html
<ul class="main-nav">
  <li id="home"><label for="homeState">Home</label></li>
  <li><label for="aboutState">About</label></li>
  <li><label for="portfolioState">Portfolio</label></li>
  <li><label for="contactState">Contact</label></li>
</ul>

<input type="radio" name="mainNavState" id="homeState" checked>
<div id="home_div"> My Home Stuff </div>
<input type="radio" name="mainNavState" id="aboutState">
<div id="about_div"> My About Stuff </div>
<input type="radio" name="mainNavState" id="portfolioState">
<div id="portfolio_div"> My Portfolio Stuff </div>
<input type="radio" name="mainNavState" id="contactState">
<div id="contact_div"> My Contact Stuff </div>
```